# What does this chemical formula mean?

Tags: solid-state-chemistry, minerals

Wikipedia says the formula of aluminum oxynitride is this $\ce{(AlN)_x·(Al2O3)_{1−x}}$,
$0.30 \leq x \leq 0.37$ . What does this formula mean?

Comment: I don't even understand it.

Comment: Go through Non-stoichiometric defects of Crystal Lattice , such as metal excess defects, metal deficiency defects etc. You may find your answer

Comment: @Hark Have you been taught the simplest of on-stoichiometric defects? Forget the $x$, instead, do you understand what $\ce{Fe_{1.98}O}$ means?

Comment: No i don't know about that

Comment: @GaurangTandon what _does_ $\ce{Fe_{1.98}O}$ mean?  Usually I see $\ce{Fe_{0.947}O}$ or something similar.

Comment: @OscarLanzi Oh, sorry. I was about to write $\ce{Fe_{0.98}O}$ to highlight the non-stoichiometric metal deficiency defect. I made a typo by mistake.

Comment: OK.  So much for iron suboxide :-).

Comment: @Hark That just means non-stoichiometry. The composition varies according to crystal defects.